# how to stop a fixed sidebar from going on top of footer?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a sample page with fixed header, fixed sidebar, and sticky footer. I would like the page to be responsive as well.

I have a fixed sidebar and I have a right border on it. I would like the border and the sidebar to stop right when the footer begins.

I have a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15278/

Here is the css I'm using for the sidebar

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid red
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `z-index` so the footer sits on top the sidebar.

**CSS**

```
.footer {
  z-index:1000;
} 

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Here's a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/wzjvebsp/2/).

Comment: Thanks. I think that will work. I noticed that the `move-left` class I added to move the main content of the site to the left -- is not responsive. Is there another way to move the content to the right such that it is responsive?

Comment: I'm not seeing a `move-left` class in there.

Comment: It is on line 68 in the html and line 63 in the CSS

Comment: I'm not up-to-speed on Bootstrap's setup but from the examples I've seen it doesn't appear the HTML/CSS structure is what Bootstrap recommends for your desired layout. Ex. [sidebar example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index`

```
.footer {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Here's a working [fork](https://jsfiddle.net/t1ye8tLL/)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make the footer also `position: fixed;`  with a `z-index`higher than the sidebar

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ue49tzet/